# String array cannot be resolved as variable

Tags: java

Is it possible in Java to redefine value after it already been defined(Like in JavaScript)? Take a look at my sample code, I am trying to redefine String array.

```
    public String[] checkIfLengEnglish (){
        String language =  Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage() ;
        String LG = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();

        if(LG.contains("en")){
            String language[] = {"English"}; // Redefining
        }
        else {
            String Language[] = {"English/"+ Language,Language,"English"}; // Redefining
        }

        return Language[];
    }
```

Comment: where you return `colors[]`?

Comment: you have `Language` defined 3 times. the one you return is not an array.

Comment: There are some Java basics to learn here.

Comment: @ David M Oh well, all 3 are proper arrays, its just the wrong syntax

Comment: @GyroGearless - `String Language =  Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage() ;` isn't an array. `getDisplayLanguage()` returns a `String` (http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#getDisplayLanguage%28%29)  (not that it really matters)

Comment: The screenshot is not even the same as the code snippet. This question is very low quality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. you re-define `Language` in your code with multiple types at multiple scopes (once at the method level, twice in the if-block/else-block). Don't do that.
2. You don't need to add the `[]` to reference an array variable, don't do that.
3. Since you declare the array *inside* the if-block, it only *exists* inside the if-block. To fix this, you need to declare it outside:

   ```
   String[] languages;
   if( LG.contains("en")){
       languages = new String[] {"English"};
   }else {
       languages = new String[] {"English/"+ Language,Language,"English"};
   }
   return languages;
   ```

   Since you no longer use initalization (which can only happen when you declare a variable) but assignment, you need to use the "long form" for specifying the array values, which includes `new String[]`.

Also note that as a general guideline, method and variable names should start with a lower-case letter and class/interface/enum names should start with a capital letter. That's not technically required, but following this guideline will make your code easier to understand for others.

Answer (score 0):

Language[] is defined inside your if/else statement. You should try putting it above that like

```
String[] array = new String[];

   if(true){
       array = {"English"};
   }

   return array;
```

// dummy example

Answer (score 0):

just reframing your code & variables for better understanding purpose

```
public String[] CheckIfLengEnglish (){
    String displayLanguage =  Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage() ;
    String LG = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
    String arrayLanguages[];
    if( LG.contains("en")){
        arrayLanguages = {"English"};
        }else {
        arrayLanguages = {"English/"+ Language,Language,"English"};
    }
    return arrayLanguages ;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

String[] Language=new String[];

if
{

Language={"English"}

}

else {

String Language[] = {"English/"+ Language,Language,"English"};
     }

return Language[] ;

Comment: You can not do sth like: `String[] Language=new String[];` - You have to provide dimension and of course `Language={"English"}` is also error.